# Check if variable contains x in PostgreSQL function

Tags: regex, postgresql, sql-function

In a PostgreSQL function, what is the syntax to check if a variable passed in contains a 
specific letter?

The variable being passed to the function is comma separated list of letters and I want to check if this list contains the letter a or x.

I imagine the code would look something like this:

```
-- var typically looks like 'a,b,c,x'
if (some way of stripping anything other than a and x from var) ~* [ax]
  -- Do something else
end if;
```

I assume regex is the answer, I'm just not 100% sure about the syntax.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to check if a string contains a substring or a letter is

```
if ( var like '%x%')
  -- Do something else
end if;
```

Or you can use regexp as you mentioned:

```
if ( var ~* 'x')
```

Comment: Oops - sorry, I had a typo. I need to check for a OR x. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: I ended up just using if (var ~* 'a' OR var ~* 'x') using what you confirmed in your second example. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @Matt You can use `var ~* 'x|a'`

Comment: The like comparison is about 9 times slower than the regular expression.